# Return pandas groupby based on input

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot

I'm trying to display different DataFrames based on user input.

I have created a script requesting for user input: 
`myscript.py`

```
import libs.mssql as mssql

db = mssql.Database()

table_name = input("Please key in A, B or C: ")

table = db.WAP(table_name)
print(table)

input("Press Enter to exit.")
```

The script should print out an output based on the class function below:

```
class Database():
    def __init__(self):
        self.cnxn = pyodbc.connect(cnxn details)

    def WAP(self, table_name):
        sql = "EXECUTE Contract_Balance"
        df = pd.read_sql(sql, self.cnxn)

        A_filter = (df.Table_Name == 'A')
        B_filter = (df.Table_Name == 'B') & (df.Product != 'C')
        C_filter = (df.Table_Name == 'C') & (df.Product == 'C')

        # Copy from df based on filters

        A = df[A_filter].copy()
        B = df[B_filter].copy()
        C = df[C_filter].copy()

        myDict = {"A": A, "B": B, "C": C} 

        if table_name in ('A', 'C'):
            table = myDict[table_name]
            group = ['Delivery', 'Product']

        elif table_name == 'B':
            table = myDict[table_name]
            group = ['Delivery', 'Region']

        return np.round(
            table.groupby(group).\
            apply(lambda x: pd.Series([np.average(x.Product_Price, weights=x.Balance),x.Balance.sum()],index=['Product_Price', 'Balance'])).\
            unstack().\
            swaplevel(1,0,axis=1).\
            sort_index(axis=1).\
            replace(np.nan, 0) 
        , 2).replace(0, '')
```

The variables are `table` and `group`.

Based on user input for the `table` (A, B or C), the variable `group` would change as well and affect the final output.

`myscript.py` fails with the error:
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'groupby'`, due to Python parsing the user input as a string, therefore the variables A, B and C (which have been defined in the class function `WAP`) are not returned.

The expected result is that `myscript.py` prints out the correct table and group based on user input of `A`, `B` or `C`

Edit: Add a dictionary and looking it up with the function call solves this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add if statements like 
`if table == 'A':
    table = A`

Comment: thanks @Joshua-Pierce i managed to do just that by defining a dictionary and looking it up with the function call. Have edited my question.. thanks for your help